# Emoji Story, The First

Tags: visual, rebus, emoji

A story told through emoji.  Could be a book, show, movie, or some other kind of story.  Can you figure out what story is depicted below?

⚗❓⚡✔⚔⚗⚔⚡⚔☠⚡☀⏪

I made this on Android, so just in case it looks weird on a different platform, here's an image:

[image: Android image version]

Hint:

> The most iconic bit of the movie is this bit:
>  [image]

Hint 2:

> =2⃣
>  [image: alien = nose2]

Comment: rocky - it's about boxing

Comment: I think you better use picture, many computer can not show the emoji rightly (including mine)

Comment: @JamalSenjaya Was just thinking that.  Updated.

Comment: A story with aliens and pigs. I have no idea, but it intrigues me a lot!

Comment: what is supouse to be the little "x" ?(at the end of the first line in the image e.g)

Comment: I believe that is a pair of swords, what is the first icon tho? some chemical instrument?

Comment: @MarioGarcia i searched the icon and its an alembic

Comment: Love the idea btw

Comment: @MarioGarcia I saw it online somewhere and thought it would be fun to make one.  I now know so many more emoji that are on my phone.

Comment: Is this a relatively well known movie?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I would imagine so.  Was #1 at the box office when it came out.  There's apparently almost 20 in the series now.

Comment: Is this animated movie? If not, I think I got it, but cant figure out which one from series...

Comment: @smriti It is an animated movie.

Comment: More puzzles like this pls! I enjoyed it :P Did you made it all by yourself or did you use any tool/help?

Comment: @MarioGarcia I made it myself using the StackExchange app on my phone while watching the movie.  I have ideas for a few others I want to make, but I want to include clues in the question title that point to the specific story and need to think up good ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I thought it is one of the bond movie(ahh... how foolish)
It is

> Pokémon: The First Movie

pigs emoji representing

> mew

and
Second hint gives

> mewtwo

Here is the link

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_The_First_Movie
>  I remember pikachu crying over petrified ash

Comment: I was super close to giving a [third hint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bmiOS.png) which I imagine would have given it away relatively quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going with...

> **Matrix**

Why?

> The strange eyes first, meaning the drugs for Neo, a helicopter, Agent Smith... There is also the aliens attacking the spaceship, the cat...

Not sure 100%, but worth a try!

EDIT: After some investigation, rather than just guessing, I've found this might be the film:

> **Virus**

I haven't seen the film, but after reading a bit about it I think it fits really good.

> There are the robotic aliens, the fights, the boat having problems in electric storms. Also, someone having to runaway in a helicopter I believe.

Comment: Good guesses, but neither of these are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.  And cheating?  Via http://emojitranslate.com:

> alembic, dizzy face, collision, fire, helicopter, man in business suit levitating, robot face, flexed biceps, collision, alien monster,?, pot of food ⚡ dragon face, incoming envelope ✔ cloud with lightning, water wave, no bicycles, swimmer, rowboat, water wave, turtle, cyclone, european castle, party popper, alien monster, crossed swords, rocket, smiling cat face with open mouth, syringe, alembic, stadium, crossed swords, alien monster ⚡ collision, stadium, dagger knife, pig nose, crossed swords, alien monster, collision, moyai, skull and crossbones ⚡ loudly crying face, droplet ☀ slightly smiling face, thumbs up sign, black left-pointing double triangle, cloud with lightning, white sun with small cloud, pig nose

(Community-wikified, feel free to edit.)

Comment: I wouldn't call it cheating. I would note that the images are not all meant to represent what they literally are. For example, the pig nose is not representing anything pig-like or nose-related.  Didn't even realize it was a pig nose, just looked like something from the movie.

Comment: Glad if this computerized translation doesn't hurt, @DavidStarkey, I sat on it for most of a day out of consideration but couldn't resist any longer.

Comment: From your comment I guess the emoji is a depiction of the events in the movie and not a cipher.  Therefore my most obvious guess is of course the Mel Brooks move, "History of the World: Part I"

Comment: @jmb.mage You are correct (not about the movie title but about it not being a cipher)